# AngularJS Filter by Inline Expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, expression, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to add an inline Angular filter that filters via an expression that evaluates to true or false. Here's my JS:

```
angular.module('programApp', [
    'programApp.controllers',
]);
angular.module('programApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('programController', ['$scope', '$filter',  
    function($scope, $filter){

      $scope.advancedFilters = 1;

      $scope.bars = [
        {'name':'First',
          'id':1},
        {'name':'Second',
          'id':2},
        {'name':'Third',
          'id':3},
        {'name':'Fourth',
          'id':4},
        {'name':'Fifth',
          'id':5}];
    }]);
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="programApp" ng-controller="programController">
  <label>Level: 
    <select ng-model="advancedFilters">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </label>

  <div ng-repeat="bar in bars | filter:advancedFilters <= bar.id">
    <h3>{{bar.name}}</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see how I'm trying to filter the bar ng-repeat based on what's in the advancedFilters dropdown. However, when I try and add a filter that evaluates to true or false to the ng-repeat, I get thrown an angular error.

I would like to avoid creating a custom function in this situation. If possible, the filter should remain inline in the HTML.

This seems pretty simple, but it isn't working. What am I doing wrong here?

**Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/trueScript/pen/LVZKEo**

Comment: It seems that you can't avoid controller in this case.

Comment: I was worried that would be the case. It seems like the sort of thing you should be able to do inline, though.

Comment: Well actually you can. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to avoid using controller you can use `ngInit` directive to create [comparator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) expression, it will be reinitialized on every iteration. Something like this:

```
<div ng-init="test = bar.id >= advancedFilters" 
     ng-repeat="bar in bars | filter:{id:advancedFilters}:test">
    <h3>{{bar.name}}</h3>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNBeqb

Comment: Ah, okay. So, I have to decide whether I'd rather throw in an nginit, or just resort to a custom filter. Thanks!